# Changing last modified date or time via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to change a file or folders last modified date/time via PowerShell?

I have a folder `folder1/` and I want to change the last modified date and time of that folder and it's contents via PowerShell.

Answer (score 58):

Get the file object then set the property:

```
$file = Get-Item C:\Path\TO\File.txt
$file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
```

or for a folder:

```
$folder = Get-Item C:\folder1
$folder.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)
```

Comment: This can be done in one line, as `(Get-Item C:\Path\To\File.txt).LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)`

Comment: weird for folder doesn't seem to work

Comment: It seems like for folders recurse solutions below are necessary, and it won't apply to the "top level" folder.

Answer (score 27):

The following way explained [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/414-changing-last-modified-and-creation-date-or-time-via-powershell.html) works for me. So I used:

```
Get-ChildItem  C:\testFile1.txt | % {$_.LastWriteTime = '01/11/2005 06:01:36'}
```

Do not get confused by the "get-*" command... it will work regardless that it is a get instead of write or something. Keep also noted as written in the source that you need to use YOUR configured data format and maybe not the one in my example above.

Comment: That would be for all files within a folder. If it's just a single file, you could do (gci C:\testFile1.txt).LastWriteTime = '01/11/2005 06:01:36'. You can also replace the 'time' with Get-Date to dynamically set the current timestamp.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible to change the **last modified date**. Here is a one liner example

```
powershell foreach($file in Get-ChildItem folder1) {$(Get-Item $file.Fullname).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date).AddHours(-5)}
```

Comment: This was useful for me thanks. The `Get-ChildItem` also has a `-Recurse` option so you can also do it for the entire tree.

Answer (score 9):

To do a kind of unix `touch` in powershell on all files :

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path . –File –Recurse) | % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)}
```

or all files and folders:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path . –Recurse) | % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)}
```

Answer (score 0):

get-childitem d: \ * -recurse | % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)}

This works for all files and folders in a tree.