# "Date modified" of downloaded file is in the past - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

I like to order most of my folders by "date modified". But sometimes I will download a file with a timestamp in the past. This is very disruptive to me (I have to check chrome downloads to find the name of the file, then do a windows search in my downloads folder to find it etc.). I would like files to be arranged in (at least most cases) folders according to the date that they got into that particular folder as opposed to when the file was created originally, a date which persists through duplications.

For example, if I duplicate "old file" which has a "date modified" stamp in the past, Id like "old file - copy" to be timestamped for today.

I don't know which keywords to even search for, is there a default way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If a file is copied, not moved, then the date created will be the date of copy. Use a date created column in Explorer.

Comment: @user1292580 when I download a media file, date modified and date created are in the past.

Comment: Whether the date modified changes or not when downloading a file likely depends on the server and protocol used. You can change the date modified using PowerShell: https://superuser.com/questions/924365/changing-last-modified-date-or-time-via-powershell

Comment: Some browsers or downloaders set the date of the local file to the date the remote file, try with different programs